# Installshield Silent Install Log

Tags: installshield

I've been given a silent install from a 3rd party (made with Installshield) I need to include as part of the project I am working on at the moment.

I've got it all working right up until I burn it to a DVD and attempt the install.

Installshield in silent install mode writes a log file to the same directory as setup.exe.  Being on a DVD this is a read only folder.

I see I can change the default location of the log file using a command line switch, but is there a way to make it not create one at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struck the same problem. I tried:

```
Setup.exe /s /f2null
```

And I couldn't find a log file anywhere afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

For each setup.exe that build by installsheild, you can use f2"logpath" parameter to specify the log file in your own script.

Comment: I know I can redirect it, that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

If 3rd party "setup.exe" creates a log automatically - the easiest solution it redirect this log to %temp% directory.

Comment: So to confirm you can't stop Installshield from logging on a silent install?

Comment: Not exactly, there is option in InstallShield which enable logging to specified directory. Perhaps, in your case it enabled to creating log file in current directory with installer.